# How to create an Ilist from DataTable with unknown columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a DataTable that was built from dynamically created SQL, so I do not know the number of columns in the datatable.

How can I convert this datatable into an IList?

EDIT: I am then going to use this to send to a Telerik Grid on the page.

Comment: Into an `IList` of what?

Comment: Because of the lack of any details, part of me really wants to just post DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList()

Comment: I want to feed this list to a Telerik Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your edited question, you can simply bind the grid directly to the `DataTable`.  (Or to its `DefaultView`)

You don't need a separate `IList`.

Comment: But if I don't know the column names how can I display it using the MVC Grid?

Comment: @John: The grid should automatically create columns.  Also, you can find the column names by looking at the `ColumnName` property in the table's `Columns` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IList<Dictionary<string, object>>` like this:

```
table.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(r => table.Columns.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c]))
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (var row in table.Rows)
   list.Add(row);

return list;
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants.